# htaccess: замена середины ссылки

Tags: php, yii2, .htaccess, apache

Народ, вопрос простой, но разобраться не могу самостоятельно. Никак не получается настроить .htaccess на перезапись адреса и одновременно мои правила urlManager'а. Попробую поконкретнее вопрос задать.

Ссылка, которую вводит пользователь: http://localhost/Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/calendar
Ссылка, которую надо получить для yii: http://localhost/Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/frontend/web/calendar
Здесь calendar - это по правилу urlManager'а контроллер task и экшн index (код ниже добавлю).

В данный момент .htaccess в корне проекта выглядит следующим образом:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/admin
RewriteRule ^admin\/?(.*) /Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/backend/web/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/(frontend/web|backend/web|admin)
RewriteRule (.*) /Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/frontend/web/$1
```

Тот вариант, который вы видите выше, выталкивает меня на адрес http://localhost/Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/frontend/web/ - открывается контроллер по умолчанию и я попадаю на главную страничку yii. Если откоючить urlManager и писать через параметры всё, то правило работает (?r=task/index). Если убрать htaccess, то по длинному варианту ссылки тоже получится пройти (http://localhost/Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/frontend/web/calendar).

**Да, я понимаю, что надо бы перенаправление для сервера на http://localhost/Yii2-advanced-HomeWork/ задать, чтобы он сразу туда смотрел. Но тут уже дело принципа и понимания.**

Код urlManager'а:

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'enableStrictParsing' =>true,
    'rules' => [
        '/' => 'site/index',

        // Календарь в двух режимах: индекс и отображение конкретного таска
        'calendar' => 'task/index',
        'calendar/<taskId:\d+>' => 'task/single',

        // Все возможные режимы работы модулей
        '<module:\w+>' => '<module>/',
        '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>',
        '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>', // Правило под вопросом, т.к. нигде не используется
        '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
        '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',

        // Наиболее вероятные без модулей
        '<controller>/<action><lang:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller>' => '<controller>/index',
    ],
],
```

Comment: Неужели это не показалось странным? Если такие проблемы возникают с одним урлом, скорее всего и следующие адреса тоже порадуют. Если настраивать в двух местах, рано или поздно начнут возникать конфликты.

Comment: 'enableStrictParsing' =>false,
попробуй так